# Using Bluebird with fs to read a file within each of an (variable length) array of directories

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, node.js, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm reading an array (of unknown length) of modules `package.json` files in order to extract the "style" property and store it in an array of its own:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
  , path = require('path')
  , Promise = require('bluebird')
  , fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs-extra'));

let components = [
    'comp1',
    'comp2',
    'comp3'
];
let npmScope = '@myscope';
gulp.task('getstyle', () => {
    let componentsBaseLocation = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', npmScope);
    Promise.map(components, (componentName) => {
        return fs.readFileAsync(path.join(componentsBaseLocation, componentName, 'package.json'), 'utf8')
    })
    .spread((...packageData) => {
        return packageData.map((packageDatum, i) => {
            packageDatum = JSON.parse(packageDatum);
            tempName = packageDatum.name.match(new RegExp(`${NpmScope}\/(.*?)$`))[1]
            tempStyle = path.join(componentsBaseLocation, tempName, packageDatum.style);
            return {
                name: tempName,
                style: tempStyle
            };
        });
    })
    .then(components => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(components, null, 2));
    });
});
```

This works, but I wonder if there are smarter, better, more appropriate ways to use bluebird or promises in general.

Comment: No need to use `.spread((...packageData) =>`.  Can just do `.then((packageData) =>` since the argument for a `Promise.map(...).then()` handler is already the array you want in your next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things you could simplify:

1. You don't need to use `.spread()` since the data is already in an array.
2. If you just process each file as it is read, you can avoid the `.map()` iteration entirely.
3. You can avoid some temporary variables.
4. You should declare all local variables with `const`, `let` or `var` as appropriate.

Here's modified code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
  , path = require('path')
  , Promise = require('bluebird')
  , fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs-extra'));

let components = [
    'comp1',
    'comp2',
    'comp3'
];
let npmScope = '@myscope';
gulp.task('getstyle', () => {
    const componentsBaseLocation = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', npmScope);
    Promise.map(components, (componentName) => {
        return fs.readFileAsync(path.join(componentsBaseLocation, componentName, 'package.json'), 'utf8').then(data => {
            const packageDatum = JSON.parse(data);
            const tempName = packageDatum.name.match(new RegExp(`${NpmScope}\/(.*?)$`))[1];
            return {
                name: tempName,
                style: path.join(componentsBaseLocation, tempName, packageDatum.style)
            };
        });
    }).then(components => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(components, null, 2));
    });
});
```

You may also want to handle a failure in `JSON.parse()` with a local try/catch handler so rather than end the entire operation, you can handle an individual error and continue with the rest of the processing, but that depends entirely upon how you're using this code and what you want to happen if a parse failure occurs.

You may also want to handle a failure in `packageDatum.name.match()`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I like the elimination of `spread`. But I think that the two levels that the nested `.then`s create is very reminiscent of the callback based approach I'm trying to avoid (the `then` following the `fs.readFileAsync` and the `then` following `Promise.map`. Is that foolish to wish to avoid that? Is a couple layers of `then`-nesting totally common within the promise ecosystem

Comment: Also I think `tempName` needs to be left it, because you still use it in the return `{name, style}` obj.

Comment: @1252748 - There are times when you can avoid nesting with promises and there are times where the code either requires a level of nesting or it makes the code simpler.  I thought eliminating the extra `.map()` iteration of all the results was a simplification.

Comment: @1252748 - Yes, you are correct about `tempName`.  I put it back.

Comment: Yeah I agree. There's a lot of docs out there that laud the flatness the promise chaining paradigm provides. But I know your promise rep on SO is legit so I just wanted to hear you say it definitively :-) Thanks!

Comment: @1252748 - Yeah, I think writing the simplest, clearest and correct code is generally the prime objective.  Often, that will be the flattest too, but not always.  Keep in mind that flat code, by itself, is not really an objective.  Sometimes, it's a means to an objective, but not if it sacrifices other things.